# Set Backface culling on multiple textures of an object?

Tags: materials

I have an object with 300+ materials. I would like to turn all these materials into backface culling mode. If I select all of them, and then check the backface culling box in the settings mode, only one of the material is checked. So I have to manually check each material, wich is tedious. I automated the process with this (fantastic) software https://www.robot-soft.com/automatic-mouse-keyboard.html but I am wondering if there is a faster way, with a few lines of code or a plugin ?
Best regards

Comment: what do you mean by "If I select all of them", you cannot select all materials in the user interface of blender. You can only select one. You have to use Python as in @taiyo's answer.

Comment: You are right, I selected multiple materials in the hierarchy but only one is really selected.

Answer (score 1):

Say hello to *Blender Python*. Head over to the *Scripting* tab and run this script:

```
import bpy

for material in bpy.data.objects["My Object's Name"].data.materials: # replace the string
    material.use_backface_culling = True
```

Comment: Of course you need to set `use_backface_culling = True`, I misread your question >.< Answer's fixed.

Comment: Thanks taiyo, as I got an error using the "objectname", I first select the object and modified your script to :

`import bpy
for material in bpy.context.object.data.materials:
material.use_backface_culling = True`

And it works fine !!! Sorry I don't understand how I can generate a new line in the comment.

Comment: Ok great, but it should work with the object's name (as string) too. This has also the advantage that you don't need the context or that the object must be selected. Anyway, glad it helps!

Comment: Yes finally it works with the name too, I made a mistake in the syntax ! Thanks again for your time !

Comment: @PhilippeDarcissac can u pls mark the checkmark on the answer so we can close this question as resolved.